# optimizing performance in a JavaScript animation: starfall with canvas and pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, background

I have a JavaScript animation that simulates a starfall effect using HTML canvas and "pixel" manipulation. While the animation works, I'm facing efficiency and speed issues, and I'm looking for ways to optimize the code. The animation involves creating stars that fall from the top of the screen and leaving a trail of pixels as they move. The thing is, the pixels are `divs`, and it reaches thousands.

the current JS code:

```
const content = document.getElementById("bkg-content");
const background = document.getElementById("bkg");
const ctx = content.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });

let stars = [];
const maxStars = 20; // Maximum number of stars

let last_x = 0;
let next_spawn = 0;

function getX(size) {
    let random = Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - size);
    return last_x - size > random || random > last_x + size ? random : getX(size);
}

function createStar() {
    let transparency = Math.random();
    let size = transparency * 200 + 100;
    let x = getX(size)
    let fallingSpeed = Math.random() * 30 + 20;
    next_spawn = size / fallingSpeed * 500;

    last_x = x;
    return {
        x,
        y: 0,
        size,
        transparency,
        rotationAngle: 0,
        rotationSpeed: Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.05,
        rotationDirection: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1,
        fallingSpeed,
    };
}

function spawnStars(count) {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        stars.push(createStar());
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        spawnStars(1)
    }, next_spawn)

    console.log(stars.length);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, content.width, content.height);

    for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        let star = stars[i];
        star.rotationAngle += star.rotationSpeed * star.rotationDirection;
        star.y += star.fallingSpeed;

        if (star.y > window.innerHeight + star.size / 2) {
            // Remove stars that have completely passed the bottom of the screen
            stars.splice(i, 1);
            i--; // Adjust the loop variable since the array length has changed
        } else {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(star.x + star.size / 2, star.y);
            ctx.rotate(star.rotationAngle);

            // Adjust transparency based on star size
            ctx.globalAlpha = star.transparency;
            console.log(ctx.globalAlpha)

            ctx.drawImage(starTXT, -star.size / 2, -star.size / 2, star.size, star.size);

            // Reset global alpha for subsequent drawings
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
}


function resizeCanvas() {
    content.width = window.innerWidth;
    content.height = window.innerHeight;

    spawnStars(Math.min(maxStars, 1)); // Initially spawn one star

    setInterval(() => {
        createPixels()
        draw()
    }, 500);
}

function createPixels() {
    const pixel = { size: 9, gap: 3 };
    const numX = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / (pixel.size + pixel.gap));
    const numY = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / (pixel.size + pixel.gap));

    background.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numX}, ${pixel.size}px)`;
    background.innerHTML = ''; // clear existing pixels

    for (let x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
            const child = document.createElement("div");
            child.classList.add("pixel");
            background.appendChild(child);
        }
    }

    const children = Array.from(background.getElementsByClassName("pixel"));

    children.forEach((child) => {
        const rect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
        const { data } = ctx.getImageData(rect.left, rect.top, pixel.size, pixel.size);

        const averageColor = getAverageColor(data);
        const color = `rgb(${averageColor}, ${averageColor}, ${averageColor})`;

        child.style.backgroundColor = color;
        child.style.boxShadow = `0 0 10px ${color}`;
    });
}

function getAverageColor(data) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        sum += data[i];
    }


    const averageColor = sum / (data.length / 4);

    return averageColor;
}

const starTXT = new Image(1600, 1600);
starTXT.src = "star.png";

starTXT.onload = resizeCanvas;

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
```

Another problem is resizing, so that it is optimal and fast, the code lags lots. Any tips? Any different approaches I could take?

[the result I aimed for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve9hO.jpg)

The current implementation seems to have performance bottlenecks. I suspect the loop in the draw function and the frequent manipulation of the canvas might be causing slowdowns. How can I optimize the code to improve efficiency? The animation speed is crucial for a smooth user experience. Are there any specific techniques or best practices I should follow to enhance the speed of the starfall effect? I'm using a combination of canvas drawing for stars and pixel manipulation for the background. Is this the most optimal approach, or are there alternative methods that could provide better performance?

I've already tried some basic optimizations like using requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval, but I'm looking for more insights and suggestions from the community. Any help in identifying and addressing the performance issues in the code would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if my code is any messy or unreadable, I've tried a lot.

EDIT: the HTML file is underneath

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>...</title>

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: black;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* Prevent scrolling */
        }

        #bkg-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0%;
        }

        #bkg {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            gap: 3px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .pixel {
            width: 9px;
            height: 9px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="bkg-content"></canvas>
    <div id="bkg"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can we have the HTML you used too?

Comment: @Spectric I've edited the message, it's there now.

Comment: Hoooooo - I think I'm going to use this next time I need to stress test my CPU ;)

Comment: @Spectric Yeah you are right, it eats up about 10% of mine :D

Comment: OK I've taken a look. Your biggest bottleneck appears to be `createPixels`. Correct me if I'm wrong: you are redrawing every single pixel each iteration?

Comment: @Spectric Yep. I feel like there was not a better way to actually approach the effect better. Basically I'm having a content canvas, and then a grid of squares that take the average color of the content behind each individual "pixel". There may be different approaches than mine, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Your code definitely doesn't have to be this slow. This demo only does one star at a time, but doesn't redraw every single pixel. This should give you an idea of how fast it can be: https://jsfiddle.net/ex47gt5d/2/

Comment: Take note that once the pixels are out of the screen, you should remove them to prevent  a 'Max call stack exceeded' error. In the example I did this by automatically removing them after 10 seconds.

Comment: @Spectric Thank you, that is pretty cool. It's almost double the speed. I'm just disappointed that I can't find an actual better way to do this. I thought of blurring the canvas and pixelating it afterwards, tried this in design program but didn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Let me take a shot at this with CSS.

Comment: Can you give a code sample that segments the star into pixels (I'm not very familiar with your code)? I don't want any animations, just a canvas with the star segmented.

Comment: @Spectric It's the part with
```
children.forEach((child) => {
    const rect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    const {
      data
    } = ctx.getImageData(rect.left, rect.top, pixel.size, pixel.size);

    const averageColor = getAverageColor(data);
    const color = `rgb(${averageColor}, ${averageColor}, ${averageColor})`;

    child.style.backgroundColor = color;
    child.style.boxShadow = `0 0 10px ${color}`;
  });```
``` in my code. It's more complex, maybe you should read the variables of this sample for more context.

Comment: OK I think I did it.

Comment: Give me a second, I have to polish it.

Answer (score 1):

OK I did it.

The truth is that your code *isn't that inefficient!* It's pretty good. There are just two problems:

- you are redrawing every single pixel instead of reusing them. I corrected this by extracting the `childrens` array outside the `createPixels` function.
- you are artificially making it *seem* like your site is lagging because your `setInterval` callback is so high. This was corrected by using `requestAnimationFrame` with no delay.

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/b7pv152w/

The code, for other users' reference, can be found below:

```js
const content = document.getElementById("bkg-content");
const background = document.getElementById("bkg");
const ctx = content.getContext("2d", {
  willReadFrequently: true
});

let stars = [];
const maxStars = 20; // Maximum number of stars

let last_x = 0;
let next_spawn = 0;

function getX(size) {
  let random = Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - size);
  return last_x - size > random || random > last_x + size ? random : getX(size);
}

function createStar() {
  let transparency = Math.random();
  let size = transparency * 200 + 100;
  let x = getX(size)
  let fallingSpeed = Math.random() * 30 + 20;
  next_spawn = size / fallingSpeed * 500;

  last_x = x;
  return {
    x,
    y: 0,
    size,
    transparency,
    rotationAngle: 0,
    rotationSpeed: Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.05,
    rotationDirection: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1,
    fallingSpeed,
  };
}

function spawnStars(count) {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    stars.push(createStar());
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    spawnStars(1)
  }, next_spawn)

}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, content.width, content.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    let star = stars[i];
    star.rotationAngle += star.rotationSpeed * star.rotationDirection;
    star.y += star.fallingSpeed;

    if (star.y > window.innerHeight + star.size / 2) {
      // Remove stars that have completely passed the bottom of the screen
      stars.splice(i, 1);
      i--; // Adjust the loop variable since the array length has changed
    } else {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(star.x + star.size / 2, star.y);
      ctx.rotate(star.rotationAngle);

      // Adjust transparency based on star size
      ctx.globalAlpha = star.transparency;

      ctx.drawImage(starTXT, -star.size / 2, -star.size / 2, star.size, star.size);

      // Reset global alpha for subsequent drawings
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
}


function resizeCanvas() {
  content.width = window.innerWidth;
  content.height = window.innerHeight;

  spawnStars(Math.min(maxStars, 1)); // Initially spawn one star

  setInterval(() => {
    createPixels()
    draw()
  }, 50);
}

let drawnPixels = false;
let children = []

function createPixels() {
  const pixel = {
    size: 9,
    gap: 3
  };
  const numX = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / (pixel.size + pixel.gap));
  const numY = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / (pixel.size + pixel.gap));

  background.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numX}, ${pixel.size}px)`;

  if (!drawnPixels) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
        const child = document.createElement("div");
        child.classList.add("pixel");
        background.appendChild(child);
        children.push(child)
      }
    }
    drawnPixels = true;
  }

  children.forEach((child) => {
    const rect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    const {
      data
    } = ctx.getImageData(rect.left, rect.top, pixel.size, pixel.size);

    const averageColor = getAverageColor(data);
    const color = `rgb(${averageColor}, ${averageColor}, ${averageColor})`;

    child.style.backgroundColor = color;
    child.style.boxShadow = `0 0 10px ${color}`;
  });
}

function getAverageColor(data) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    sum += data[i];
  }


  const averageColor = sum / (data.length / 4);

  return averageColor;
}

const starTXT = new Image(1600, 1600);

starTXT.src = "" //INSERT SOURCE HERE

starTXT.onload = resizeCanvas;

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>...</title>

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: black;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* Prevent scrolling */
        }

        #bkg-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0%;
        }

        #bkg {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            gap: 3px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .pixel {
            width: 9px;
            height: 9px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="bkg-content"></canvas>
    <div id="bkg"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually, I just realized that, because it is so fast, it is creating the illusion that it is lagging. You can try this one, which has a 100ms delay per render: https://jsfiddle.net/7f0184o9/

Comment: @EliášJanProcházka This was a fun puzzle to solve ;). Enjoy your holidays ‍‍‍

Comment: Great answer! It's indeed like a puzzle to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get good animation speed is to do it via CSS Animation, rather than trying to do it with JS.

An introduction to CSS Animation is a bit beyond a SO answer, so here is an intro to the subject on MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: I think you haven't read the code to be honest. This is not really possible using CSS, at least not by my knowledge. If you've got any specific tips that are actually useful here, let me know.

Comment: @EliášJanProcházka actually, perhaps a CSS method is worth exploring? E.g., using CSS to create a 'pixel' effect. The animation (going down, rotating) is quite trivial then.